# Remove more than one module at once

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

after install on module like `nb store` some sub module installed in dotnetnuke too, for unistaling installed module should click on recycle bin for each submodule to uninstall them and it's waste of time, how is it possible to do in easier way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not an easier way to handle this.  If the module developer defined multiple definitions when they are added that is the way that it works.

once added, each module must be removed individually.